# django-filter conjoined not working as expected

Tags: python, django, django-filter

I'm using [django-filter](http://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/ref/filters.html) in my application in order to implement some basic filtering. By default, `django-filter` does an `OR` query but I want to do an `AND` query.

I've tried using `conjoined=True` as described in the docs, but it's still returning results using `OR`.

My code looks like this:

```
class ReservationFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    tags = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(queryset=Tag.objects.all(), conjoined=True)
```

where `tags` is a m2m key in `Reservation` model:

```
`tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name='tags')`
```

How can I build an `AND` query?

Comment: I'm sure this has nothing to do with anything, and I don't know `django-filter`, but do you really have a field `tags` with `related_name='tags'`?  That seems like a recipe for confusion.

Comment: SInce the `tags` are an attribute of the `Reservation` class, it would be much better to change the `related_name` to reflect this: `tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name='reservations')`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem for ForeignKey relation.
I gave conjoined=False param and it worked. The query was as `AND`.
But it can confuse, that's why I use custom method to write my logic as I want it works:

```
def my_custom_method(queryset, name, value):
    pass

django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(
    method=my_custom_method, conjoined=True, queryset=your_qs
)
```